# show a divider at bottom of loop except for last item

Tags: php, loops, foreach

So I know this is simple but I've been banging my head against the wall for a while trying to figure it out. I want to show a ruler at the bottom of my loop on each one except the last one. I can get it to work if I have the exact number of records but not if I have less. For example if the max number to show is 10 but there are only 5 records I want the divider after the 4th record. Likewise, if there are 20 results but max is 10 I want it after the 9th.

```
        <?php $subscriberIDs = ba_getUsersByRole( 'subscriber' );
        // Loop through each user
        $i=0;
        $max = 10; //max number of results
        $total_users =count($subscriberIDs); //total number of records
        foreach($subscriberIDs as $user) : 
        if($i<=$max) : ?>

        <li>   
                       <?echo $user['data'];?>
        </li>

        <?php 
        if(($i < $total_user-1 && $max >= $total_users) || ($i < max-1 &&  $total_users <= $max)){echo "<hr>";}
    $i++;

        endif; 
        endforeach; ?
```

Comment: What's with the colons, is this even valid PHP?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, it is. It's a way to use PHP without braces. It's used a lot in templates.

Comment: are you talking about around the `if` and `foreach`? If so yes It's valid: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @icktoofay: Wow..learn something new every day.

Comment: @Mark It's called [alternate control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: There shouldn't be an `hr` immediately inside an `ol` or `ul`.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2.  Use CSS to add a rule if you want it there and use the `:last-child` pseudo class to remove the rule for the last item.

Comment: @thetaiko Thanks, this isn't at all close to the final css layout. I'm probably not even going to use `ul` Just wanted to get the loop working first. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// <hr> goes in every spot, but not on the last item, up to 10
$position = min($max-1, count($subscriberIDs)-1);
$i = 0;
foreach($subscriberIDs as $user){
   echo '<li>' . $user['data'] . '</li>';
   if($i != $position){
       echo '<hr>';
   }
   $i++;
}
```

This takes the lesser of either `$max-1` or `count($subscriberIDs)-1`, which by definition is will be the *last* item you'll iterate over.  If you have more than `$max` items, then this will be `$max-1`, if you have less than `$max` items, then this will be `count(.)-1`.

Then, during the iteration, the `if` statement prints an `<hr>` so long as the current item is *not* the *last* item.

Comment: I want a ruler for EACH item EXCEPT the last. I think your code is doing the oppisite

Comment: @Bandon: okay, misread I guess, this now puts an <hr> after every item except the 9th or next-to-last item, is that what you want?

Comment: @Bandon: that'd be safe to do.

Comment: @Bandon [`min`](http://php.net/min) returns the lowest value of the arguments given.

Comment: So basically you are saying get the lowest value and make sure that `$position` does not equal that?

Comment: @mark, thanks. I like learning WHY things work not just having them work :)